# how to makes tkinter works on android devices？

Tags: python, android, user-interface, tkinter

I need a app that support users edit and run python code,i need show the result to user.
And the app must support user use turtle module.

I tried turmux qpython python-for-android,i am already able to run simple python code,but tkinter module all failed.
I have checked relevant information and learned that tkinter only supports desktop systems, does not support mobile devices. Pydroid3 support tkinter,but I don’t know why it works.
My app really need use turtle module ,turtle need tkinter,so i need some help for how to make tkinter works on android.
Be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Unclear if you've read: https://learning-python.com/using-tkinter-programs-on-android.html and specifically https://learning-python.com/mergeall-android-scripts/_README.html#androwish

Comment: ye, i will read it ,hope i can get some ideas. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

pydroid is a great application, I used it for a while until I had a computer, you can easily find it on the playstore.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&pcampaignid=web_share

Comment: I have it and  researched. What I want  is how pydroid3 works.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).